# Export Pandas Dataframe to well-formed CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pickle

I have a cycle in which on every iteration I export the pandas dataframe to a CSV file. The problem is that i got an output as you see in the first picture, but i need to get something similar to the second one.
I also tried with some encoding type, such as utf-8, utf-16, but nothing changed.

The only difference between my solution and the ones found online is that my dataframe is built from a pickle file, but I don't think this is the problem.

```
    for pickle_file in files:
    key = pickle_file.split('/')[5].split('\\')[1] + '_' + pickle_file.split('/')[5].split('\\')[4]
    with lz4.frame.open(pickle_file, "rb") as f:
        while True:
            try:
                diz[key].append(pickle.load(f))
            except EOFError:
                break

for key in diz.keys():
    a = diz[key]
    for j in range(len(a)):
        t = a[j]
        for index,row in t.iterrows():
            if row['MODE'] != 'biflow':
                w = row['W']
                feature = row['FEATURE']
                mean = row['G-MEAN']
                rmse = row['RMSE']
                df.loc[-1] = [w] + [feature] + [rmse] + [mean] + [key]
                df.index = df.index + 1
    df = df.sort_values(by = ['W'])
    df.to_csv(path + key + '.csv', index = False)
    df = df[0:0]
```

[image: MyResult]
[image: DesiredResult]

Answer (score 0):

The data is correctly formed. What you need to do is split each row into columns. In MS Excel it's Data > Text to Columns and then follow the function wizard.

If you are using a different application for opening the data, just google how to split text row data into columns for that application.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have about 100 output files that need to be formatted correctly, doing it manually every run would cost me so much time. Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of services online providing exactly what you want. I don't know if they are free or secure, but you can try your luck. 

I guess for what you want it actually makes sense to just export it in XLS already. Pandas package has that functionality in-built, it will be much easier to use it that way. Check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exporting-a-pandas-dataframe-to-an-excel-file/